# How to Add the configuration file to my project After Enabling Google+ Api

Tags: android, google-plus

I am using android studio to integrate Google+ Api in my application but I am confused how to add configuration file to my project.

Can anyone help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: In androidhive they are using eclipse but I m using android studio

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: Ya I got it .thank you

Comment: Try this [Sample for google plus](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-google-plus-api-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Download .json file from here https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=default-demo-app-6057a

2.move "Downloaded .json file path"  "Project path upto app folder

3.Type command like this in Terminal

move "C:\Users\pc43\Downloads\google-services.json"    "D:\Dummy\xxxx\Google+Project\app"

Comment: how to add configuration file to my project using eclipse

Comment: I am explained above steps using android studio.Refer android hive tutorial for eclipse

Comment: Followed steps in android hive but google plus name, image and id become null.